# How Would like Make A Two Column Table With Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

```
+-----------+-----------+
|    12     |    16     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    13     |    17     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    14     |    18     |
+-----------+-----------+
|    15     |           |
+-----------+-----------+
```

How can I make this in twigs file???

Comment: You need to specify more details in the questions and what you tried if you want to get an answer. And also look at the tutorials.

Comment: Welcome. This question is very low quality, there is just not enough information to give an answer. Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have commented, there does need to be a little bit more information, but this might work:

```
{% set arr = [ 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 ] %}
{% set halfway = (arr|length / 2)|round %}
{% set col1 = arr|slice(0, halfway) %}
{% set col2 = arr|slice(halfway, arr|length - halfway) %}
<table>
    <tbody>
        {% for i in 0..col1|length %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ col1[i]|default('') }}</td>
            <td>{{ col2[i]|default('') }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is untested but the general idea is:

- split your original array into two, one for each column
- iterate through the length of the first column (which should be longest, the logic above doesn't ensure this though, that's an exercise for you)
- output one item from each of the column arrays

It's not elegant and I would question why you're doing this with a table considering tables are columns and rows. Ideally you'd change your data before it hit Twig so you're doing as little logic in your templates as possible.

Comment: It's working.... :)   and how to slice for col3 and col4...